# Verb identification

Tags: verbs

Among the most important is the realization that apparently selfish traits such as envy – through which we express our discontent with inequality – **was** a useful evolutionary characteristic for building the social cohesion that enabled hunter-gatherers such as the Ju/’haonsi to thrive for as long as they did.
In the above sentence,what is the subject of verb **was**?

Comment: If you ignore the parenthetical clause (set off by hyphens), it should be obvious that *syntactically* the subject of ***was*** is in fact ***apparently selfish traits***. Because his phrasing is so convoluted, the writer has ended up confusing *himself* as well as his hapless readers, which is why he's got a singular verb form associated with a plural subject.

Comment: that means it's a typo? it should be 'were'?   or,If I strike the parenthetical clause,it will be-' Among the most important is the realization that apparently selfish traits such as envy  was a useful evolutionary ...'.Now it is possible to have a clause after such as like 'envy was a useful revolutionary ....'?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "typo", no. Imho the entire sentence is clumsy and pretentious (and *please* don't think of trying to add *more* distracting clauses, which would make it even worse!). If you just try to correct the subject/verb plurality mismatch, you'd have to switch to *were useful evolutionary **characteristics*** on the other side of the copula. But even though that "fixes" the syntax, I think it makes the *meaning* even more obscure. It's not a good example of English text for learners to analyse.

Comment: It's a typo; it should be "were".

Answer (score 1):

It needs fixing.

Among the most important {realizations} is the realization that **apparently selfish traits** such as envy -- through which we express our discontent with inequality-- **were useful evolutionary characteristics** for building the social cohesion that enabled hunter-gatherers, such as the  Ju/’haonsi, to thrive for as long as they did.

apparently selfish traits were useful evolutionary characteristics